# Average between cells with numbers separated by slashes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the result highlighted in yellow, 3.2 is the average between the numbers of the right, and 7.8 is the average of numbers of the left ¿what formula I need to use?

[image: screenshot from ms-excel]

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify the nature of the values, and edit your question to show what you have tried, and what the results have been.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel does not have O365 functions like TEXTBEFORE & TEXTAFTER and if you are on 2019 or so that supports FILTERXML & TEXTJOIN, you may try the following.

I assume the data is numbers or text but **NOT dates**.

Formula in D1.

```
=AVERAGE(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,LEFT(D2:D5,FIND("/",D2:D5)-1)),"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))) &"/"&AVERAGE(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,RIGHT(D2:D5,LEN(D2:D5)-FIND("/",D2:D5))),"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula will automatically enclose in curly braces to indicate that this is an Array Formula. This step is important.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the format and therefore the nature of the text screenshotted. Given Excel's normal formatting of variously formatted numerical material, one would think the data is dates in the "m/d" short date format ("m/d" because "d/m" would make "3/14" into an error instead).

But they could be fractions with at least two denominator places, then right justified, or just plain text.

So, for each of those, one way to do it would be the following for the basic idea (data is text formatted), then modified as follows for the other two:

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A5,"/")))

=AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A5,"/")))
```

So, `TEXTBEFORE` for the left side, `TEXTAFTER` for the right side. `VALUE` because the two text functions produce text that, since Excel has every reason to believe you want to continue to be text, will not be coerced into being numerals by using a function like `AVERAGE` (or `AGGREGATE`s averaging choice) wrapped about its output.

Lots of ways to break up the data for the above approach, but you don't ask about such in particular so I just demonstrate the  process:  break apart the data, retain only the portion you need, force (not "coerce") it into being a number, then do to it what you will, averaging in this case. Each step can be involved, each has other ways of being done, and the further back in Excel version you need to support, the more step-filled and non-general each will be.

So, for the other two kinds of data, you need to force it into being text, then replace the "A1:A5" with the formula that does so. For instance:

Dates:

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(  TEXT(A1:A5,"m/d"),  "/")))
```

Fractions:

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(  TEXT(A1:A5,"# ??/??"),  "/")))
```

Depending upon your exact data and its "cleanliness" you might need to use `AGGREGATE`, rather than choose to, or not to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older version of Excel you may need to try this:

`=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(D7:D11,(FIND("/",D7:D11)-1))))&"/"&AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(D7:D11,LEN(D7:D11)-FIND("/",D7:D11))))`
or

`=AVERAGE(--(LEFT(D28:D32,(FIND("/",D28:D32)-1))))&"/"&AVERAGE(--(RIGHT(D28:D32,LEN(D28:D32)-FIND("/",D28:D32))))`

Where your list (in text format) is in cells D7:D11

This is an array formula, so click in the formula bar above the sheet and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to activate it.